# require(): using module.exports vs assigning to "this" directly

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm wondering if there are any pros or cons when using the two approaches against each other:

first.js:

```
this.myFunction = function() {
    return 'herro first';
}
```

second.js:

```
module.exports = obj = {};
obj.myFunction = function() {
    return 'herro second';
}
```

The two above would then be included and used as so:

app.js:

```
var first = require('./first.js');
console.log(first.myFunction());

var second = require('./second');
console.log(second.myFunction());
```

Comment: Those are two distinct ways to *export* a function, not to import it.

Comment: Overwriting `module.exports` is an antipattern, especially when you don't need to. Rather do `var obj = module.exports;` (which also is *local*) or just `module.exports.myFunction = …` right away.

Comment: While using `this` does work in a module, `module.exports` is much more declarative and clear to everyone.

Comment: @Bergi Can you explain a bit more about anti pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`module.exports` (or just `exports`) is the standard CommonJS way.

In Node.js, `this` happens to be the same object, but that is best not relied on, and using `this` will not work with other tools, for example Browserify

Comment: An actual answer explaining it, ta!